# Pronunciation of "Будто"

Tags: произношение

Is this word pronounced [ˈbuttɐ] or [ˈbutɐ] ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely, the first pronunciation (`[ˈbuttɐ]`) is correct.
Double-`t` sounds like a long `t`. Tongue touches the palate, **sleeps for a moment** and untouches it.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [ˈbuttɐ] if this word is on its own:

```
После армии его будто подменили: он возмужал и стал по-другому смотреть на жизнь
```

and the latter in `как будто`:

```
Давай представим, как будто сейчас восемнадцатый век: нет ни компьютеров, ни телефонов
```

Comment: I'd use [ˈbuttɐ] for both :). Though in the second example the while word is going to receive significantly less stress in speech and end up being pronounced faster. Still, with a noticeable pause on "t". Maybe not audible for every listener but palpable for me when I am talking (making it "бута" requires me to consciously prnounce the T without stopping)

Answer (score 1):

[ˈbuttɐ] : It has a double 't' and ends with short 'o'.

Comment: I'd say that it ends by sound between 'о' and 'а'